# How to run autocmd in vim with double extension?

Tags: vim, neovim

How to make autocmd work for double extensions in vim?

This command works for .scss files

```
:autocmd BufWritePre *.css echo "hello css!"
```

But this doesn't work for blade.php

```
:autocmd BufWritePre *.blade.php echo "hello blade!"
```

Comment: `But this doesn't work for blade.php`. It won't. because `blade.php` has extension `php` instead of `blade.php` try `foo.blade.php`